# ¿Cómo hacer que cuando un div haga salto de linea a un texto dentro de él no corte la palabra?

Tags: html5, html-tabla

Tengo una tabla en `html` la cual tiene una columna llamada `nota` en esta llega un texto lineal, pero la columna se encarga de acomodarlo hacía abajo haciendo saltos de linea, la cuestión es que se corta la palabra y puede dificultar el entendimiento  al usuario que lo lea, por lo tanto quisiera saber sí hay una manera de que no la corte o que cuando la corte se coloque un **"-"** para que sea más fácil de entender, pero no encuentro la manera, sí me ayudaran se los agradezco, dejo el código de la tabla y una imagen.

`HTML`

```
<table class='table table-stripped' border=1 id="table">
                <thead class= 'thead-dark'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th style='width: 110px'>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Documento</th>
                        <th>Nombre completo</th>                            
                        <th>Sede</th>
                        <th>Siglas</th>                                                  
                        <th style='width: 200px'>Nota</th>                        
                        <th style='width: 40px'>Acciones</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <a href="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=todos"></a>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 0; $i < count($datos); $i++){
                            $id = $datos[$i]['id_controlAsis'];
                            $rutaEd = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=editar&id_controlAsis=$id";
                            $rutaEl = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=eliminar&id_controlAsis=$id";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>". ($i+1) ."</td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['fecha']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['documento']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['nombres']} {$datos[$i]['apellidos']} </td>";                                
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['sede']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['siglas']} </td>";                                                          
                            echo "<td style='word-break: break-all; width: 200px; white-space: initial'> {$datos[$i]['nota']} </td>";                            
                            echo "<td>
                            <a href='$rutaEd' class='badge badge-primary'>Editar </a>
                            <a href='$rutaEl' class='badge badge-warning'>Eliminar </a>
                            </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

`Imagen`

[image: Tabla HTML]

Comment: Hola, de partida creo que tu problema va por el style que tiene el **td** donde tienes el texto, **world-break: break-all**. saca esta propiedad y prueba poniendo **text-align: justify;** y me cuentas cómo te va

Comment: Nice men, gracias, me ayudó, colocalo como respuesta y la voto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

creo que el problema que tienes es por que el td en donde tienes el texto tiene un style, me refiero a este

```
style='word-break: break-all;
```

Esta propiedad es la que hace que te rompa las palabras y las vaya tirando hacia abajo.

Podrías probar poniendo

```
style='text-align: justify;'
```

Esto lo que hace es justificar el texto usando todo el with que tenga la caja, lo que va a hacer que las palabras que no quepan por su largo pasen para abajo.

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tiene que hacer dos cosas:

La primera, quetar del style `word-break: break-all`,  este estilo de css le va a cortar la palabra cuando llegue a la margen.

La segunda,  el texto que desea mostrar es recomendable que lo coloque dentor de una etiqueta `p` o `span`.

```
echo "<td style='width: 200px; white-space: initial'> <p style='margin: 0; padding:0;'>{$datos[$i]['nota']} </p></td>";
```